# Can I reshape and fill a number in tibble() with R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am a very novice in R programing + tidyverse.

As you can see below, I want to fill the NAs corresponding to the Item name of each row and column.

And then I want to leave only one row per a district name.

How could I do this in tidyverse or just typical R programing?

```
from

District Name     Item  Score  TB_E04a  TB_E04b TB_E04d
------------------------------------------------------------
Anderson County TB_E04a 0.51    NA  NA  NA
Anderson County TB_E04b 0.68    NA  NA  NA
Anderson County TB_E04d 0.67    NA  NA  NA
Clinton City    TB_E04a 1.00    NA  NA  NA
Clinton City    TB_E04b 1.00    NA  NA  NA
Clinton City    TB_E04d 1.00    NA  NA  NA
```

```
to

District Name     Item  Score  TB_E04a  TB_E04b TB_E04d
------------------------------------------------------------
Anderson County TB_E04a 0.51    0.51    0.68    0.67
......(So on)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  select(-starts_with("TB")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Item,
    values_from = Score
  )
```

```
  District Name   TB_E04a TB_E04b TB_E04d
  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Anderson County    0.51    0.68    0.67
2 Clinton  City      1       1       1
```

Base R: with `reshape`

```
df1 <- reshape(df,
        v.names = "Score",
        idvar = "District",
        timevar = "Item",
        direction = "wide")
df1 <- df1[,c(1:2, 6:8)]
df1
```

```
  District   Name Score.TB_E04a Score.TB_E04b Score.TB_E04d
1 Anderson County          0.51          0.68          0.67
4  Clinton   City          1.00          1.00          1.00
```

Comment: Please see my update with base !